# wordpress: Error when use ajax in plugin admin area?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i am making ajax calls in my plugin using admin-ajax . So, when there is error, i am getting error "relaod page" without showing the error . I cant see the logs as i dont have access to the server ? I tried like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("#send_newsletter").click(function() {

      var subjecttitle = jQuery("#subjecttitle").val();
      var emailtosender = jQuery("#emailtosender").val();
      var post_id = jQuery("#post_id").val();
      var action = jQuery("#action").val();
      var dataString = 'emailtosender=' + emailtosender + '&action=' + action + '&subjecttitle=' + subjecttitle + '&post_id=' + post_id;


      jQuery("#flash").show();
      jQuery("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="loading">loading</span>');

      jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php plugins_url( 'newsletter/send.php'  ); ?>",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
              jQuery("#display").after(html);
          }
      });

      return false;
  });
});
```

But when i click `#send_newsletter`  to send, its reload the page, why!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prevent the default action of the submit button but you may also have issues with the url you are using, i left a note beside that for you

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#send_newsletter").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var subjecttitle= jQuery("#subjecttitle").val();
var emailtosender= jQuery("#emailtosender").val();
var post_id= jQuery("#post_id").val();
var action = jQuery("#action").val();
var dataString = 'emailtosender='+ emailtosender+'&action='+ action+'&subjecttitle='+ subjecttitle+'&post_id='+ post_id;


jQuery("#flash").show();
jQuery("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="loading">loading</span>');

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php plugins_url( 'newsletter/send.php'  ); ?>", // you will also have issues here you should use wp's ajaxurl and have the function in your functions file + hooked to wp-ajax...see http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/ for more information
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
jQuery("#display").after(html);
});
} return false;
});
});
```